How do you automatically update the JLabel when clicking a row in JTable?
What I want to know is when I'll click a single row in a table

the table only have title, author, genre, availability
it will display the other/all of the information of that item in the table to the rightPanel.

    // this is my method for the listener
    void addTableListener() {
            ListSelectionModel selectionModel = bookTable.getSelectionModel();
            selectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                        int selectedRow = bookTable.getSelectedRow();
                        if (selectedRow != -1) { // If a row is selected
                            updateRightPanel(selectedRow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }


what I expect is when I click a row in the table, is it will update the rightPanel which is int updateRightPanel(selectedRow) method.


I'm not sure the getValueIsAdjusting method is appropriate for a ListSelectionModel.  Edit your question to create a [mre] that we can copy to our IDE, compile, and test.

not sure what the problem is - the question is describing expected behavior but nothing about actual behavior (or missing of it). Assuming it is not updating the rightPanel, three usual problems: 1) the listener is not being called at all (first point to debug, or add log/println); 2) updateRightPanel() is not updating the (correct) fields, e.g. wrong instance; 3) the rightPanel is not being re-painted after the update || we hardly can debug one single method, see previous comment

Your code looks fine, so there’s probably something amiss in your updateRightPanel method.  Edit your question and show us the code for that method.
